# Python: OOP overhead?

Tags: python, performance, oop

I've been working on a real-time application and noticed that some OOP design patterns introduce incredible overheads in Python (tested with 2.7.5).

Being straightforward, why do simple accessor methods of dictionary values take almost 5x more time when the dictionary is encapsulated by another object?

For instance, running the code below, I got:

```
Dict Access: 0.167706012726
Attribute Access: 0.191128969193
Method Wrapper Access: 0.711422920227
Property Wrapper Access: 0.932291030884
```

Executable code:

```
class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._data['id']

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._data['name']

    @property
    def score(self):
        return self._data['score']


class MethodWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data

    def id(self):
        return self._data['id']

    def name(self):
        return self._data['name']

    def score(self):
        return self._data['score']


class Raw(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name, score):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.score = score


data = {'id': 1234, 'name': 'john', 'score': 90}
wp = Wrapper(data)
mwp = MethodWrapper(data)
obj = Raw(data['id'], data['name'], data['score'])


def dict_access():
    for _ in xrange(100):
        uid = data['id']
        name = data['name']
        score = data['score']


def method_wrapper_access():
    for _ in xrange(100):
        uid = mwp.id()
        name = mwp.name()
        score = mwp.score()


def property_wrapper_access():
    for _ in xrange(100):
        uid = wp.id
        name = wp.name
        score = wp.score


def object_access():
    for _ in xrange(100):
        uid = obj.id
        name = obj.name
        score = obj.score


import timeit
print 'Dict Access:', timeit.timeit("dict_access()", setup="from __main__ import dict_access", number=10000)
print 'Attribute Access:', timeit.timeit("object_access()", setup="from __main__ import object_access", number=10000)
print 'Method Wrapper Access:', timeit.timeit("method_wrapper_access()", setup="from __main__ import method_wrapper_access", number=10000)
print 'Property Wrapper Access:', timeit.timeit("property_wrapper_access()", setup="from __main__ import property_wrapper_access", number=10000)
```

Comment: +1, that's an interesting question, but IMHO it's rarely worth it to think too much about performance with CPython - once you go CPython you have already lost the performance train. Incidentally, using PyPy Dict, Method and Property wrapper access take all the same time (which is roughly half the time of CPython's Dict access on my machine), and attribute access is ~6 times faster (i.e. 12 times faster than CPython's dict).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of the dynamic lookups the Python interpreter (CPython) is doing to dispatch all of your calls, indexing, etc. Dynamic lookups allow a great deal of flexibility in the language but at a performance cost. When you use the "Method Wrapper", this (at least) is happening:

- look up `mwp.id` - it happens to be a method, but it's also just an object assigned to an attribute and has to be looked up like any other
- *call* `mwp.id()`
- inside the method, look up `self._data`
- look up the `__getitem__` of `self._data`
- *call* the `__getitem__` (this at least will be a C function but you still had to go through all those dynamic lookups to get here)

By comparison, your "Dict Access" test case only has to look up the `__getitem__` and then invoke it.

As Matteo Italia pointed out in a comment, this is implementation specific. In the Python ecosystem now you also have PyPy (uses a JIT and runtime optimization), Cython (compiles to C, with optional static type annotations etc), Nuitka (compiles to C++, supposed to take code as-is), and multiple other implementations.

One way of optimizing these lookups in "pure" Python on CPython is to get direct references to objects and assign them to local variables outside of loops, and then use the local variables inside loops. This is an optimization that potentially comes at the cost of cluttering the code and/or breaking encapsulation.

Comment: Thanks Jason for your input. Besides a huge fan of Python, I have to confess I was a bit disappointed when I noticed that. But yes, great flexibility comes with a price.